# How can I sort ls -l /dev by type and major and minor device number?

Tags: linux, directory, device, sort

How can I sort the `/dev` directory by type and major and minor device number when doing `ls -l`?

The best way I've found so far is:

```
ls -l /dev | sort -k 1.1,1.2 -k 5n -k 6n | less
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It seems to sort correctly, is there some issue that needs solving?

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: It is fairly compact, you have marshalled the sort arguments as necessary and the whole thing could be put into a shell alias for quick access if you ever wanted to use it frequently.  Imagine writing an awk, Perl or other language script in its place.

Comment: The code of `ls` is free to be modified, the option could be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three processes is already pretty slim. You'll only make it slimmer if you could persuade `ls` to do this complex sorting itself, which you can't, or if you could dispense with the pager, which is irrelevant to what you're asking.

So I'd say no, no better way.

(The options to sort don't have any redundant fluff in them either.)